# Can I use a combination of SUBSTR() and CHARINDEX() to return a particular line in a body of text?

Tags: t-sql, substr

I am writing a T-SQL function that returns an account number from a block of text. The text is generated by the system, and has 3 colons so I need to try to find a way to use SUBSTR() on the row containing "Account:" and not just the colon itself:

Amount: $10.00

Date: 12/5/2022

Account: Mr. John Doe 83850

What would be the cleanest way to select only the line containing the account number to my function for parsing into an integer?

Comment: Yes, you can. Consider using [`reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get the _last_ colon and working from there.

Comment: I think you want PATINDEX not CHARINDEX. Then you can search for 'Account:'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll probably mess this up on my phone but something like this should help:

```
SUBSTRING(TEXT,(PATINDEX('%ACCOUNT:%',TEXT)+9),LEN(TEXT)-(PATINDEX('%ACCOUNT:%',TEXT)+9))
```

Edit:

You could find the third line by finding your 3rd carriage return and line feed using char(10)+char(13), but that could look messy going 3 levels deep so I wont attempt it on my phone